# how to display svn tree contents with correct order

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to use the svn command line to display the tree data in a certain order.

I want the following information displayed in this order:

File Name:   Revision :  Date : Size:

I am trying to use the following command but it outputs in the wrong order??

svn ls -Rv http://path.to.repo > output.txt

How can I control the order of the output

Comment: What is the output now? Could you not use `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up creating the output file and manipulating in in Word/Ecell, Thanks